# Weird Bootstrap Responsive Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having a weird problem with my first go around with Bootstrap page design.

I have three rows with four columns each in medium view.
I am collapsing them into two column rows by 
using (<)div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"(>).

All is well in the first and third row. 
But the second row isn't collapsing properly. 
The columns are askew and not snapping properly into a row side-by-side.

This is happening on two pages. 
Only the middle row is affected.

Any thoughts would be helpful.

UPDATE:

Thanks for the fiddle, discussion, and DUH moment!
They were much needed.

The original format I was working with was:

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">1</div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">2</div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">3</div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">4</div>
 </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yu22d50d/)

Comment: Could you provide all of the code? Even better would be in a http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Having 4 columns in the same row with `col-sm-6` classes is not something you should do. No matter what size (xs, sm, md, etc.) all the number values in a row should add up to 12 (not 24).

Comment: @griswoldo Good Call. Think I was trying to 'nest' divs without nesting divs. If that makes any sense.

Comment: @newneub You need to provide the code you've written, specifically the section you're having an issue with. Everyone's just taking a stab in the dark as to what you want without it.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon my comment, you could use [Bootstrap helper classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to solve your problem. Without seeing your implementation it's hard to say whether this is the best idea or not, since you should use these helper classes wisely. Given that, you could separate your column breakdown into separate divs. Code and fiddle below:

```
<div class="container visible-md visible-lg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Col 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container visible-xs visible-sm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">Col 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">Col 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/w901u5jw/1/)

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to do. But on the 2nd row it breaks.

Comment: @MattD see my comment to OP's question. Having 4 `col-sm-6` classes in one row is a bad idea.

Comment: @griswoldo Why exactly is it a bad idea? As far as I can see, I produced the same thing you did with half the markup.

Comment: @MattD ok, so maybe "bad idea" is too strong of a term here. Regardless, what the OP is experiencing is exactly what Bootstrap says will happen when more the 12 columns are specified in a row. "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line." Since he's trying to avoid that behavior, he'd have to keep his column count <= 12 per row.